# XHTML Table in table and wc3 validator problem

Tags: xhtml-transitional

I am writting a code in XHTML 1.0. When I try to validate that have answer:
 "document type does not allow element "table" here.."

`<table  width = "100%">
        <table>
               something...
        </table
    </table>`

What shall I do to avoid that error? 
I mean nesting the table in XHTML.

Comment: Put the inner table inside a table cell in the outer one. Or, ask yourself why you need this structure in the first place; the outer table is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Also, XHTML 1.0 Transitional? Why?